# Unterstellt "gibt sich unschuldig" eine Schuld?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Artikeln/Medien werden auch mal Sätze verwendet wie:

> Der Angeklagte gibt sich unschuldig oder
>   Der Manager gibt sich unwissend zur Affäre.
>   Aus Schlagzeile: Dieb gibt sich unwissend

Ich hatte das schon immer so verstanden, dass der Schreiber das nicht glaubt. Als ob er der Person unterstellt, dass es anders ist.

Irre ich hier oder ist das tatsächlich so? Unterstellt man damit der Person die man mit dem Satz beschreibt das Gegenteil vom Gesagten?

Habe das Internet und meine Enzyklopädien durchsucht aber keine Definition finden können für "gibt sich ". Hat evtl. jemand sogar eine offizielle Definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duden:

> **sich geben**
> sich in bestimmter Weise verhalten, benehmen
>
> Beispiele
>
> -sich gelassen, freundlich geben
>
> -sich als biederer Bürger, als Experte geben

Wörtlich genommen heißt das nur, dass eine Person nach außen hin darstellen will, dass sie eine bestimmte Eigenschaft hat.

Die Frage, die sich (relativ automatisch) stellt ist: "Warum sollte er so tun, als ob er [gelassen|freundlich|bieder...] wäre, wenn er's wirklich ist und das sowieso jeder sehen kann?". Ich würde nicht behaupten wollen, dass der Schreiber einer solchen Formulierung unterstellt, die Person hätte die erwähnte Eigenschaft nicht - Aber er läßt (absichtlich oder unabsichtlich) Raum für Zweifel offen.

Wollte man diese Interpretation ausschließen, würde man eher auf Verben zurückgreifen, die keine Aktivität der betrachteten Person voraussetzen, wie z.B.

> Er erscheint als biederer Bürger
>
> anscheinend ist er ...

Comment: Auf der anderen Seite: Wenn ich z.B. "ich gebe mich geschlagen" sage, erkennt jedenfalls mein Sprachgefühl nicht, dass das nur dargestellt oder vorgetäuscht sein soll.

Comment: @janka dargestellt: ja, vorgetäuscht: eher nicht. Der Wolf, der einen Machtkampf verliert (sich geschlagen gibt), zieht den Schwanz ein und "stellt den Verlierer dar" - Das hat aber nichts mit vortäuschen zu tun. Er signalisiert nur nach außen, dass er seine Niederlage akzeptiert.

Comment: Ja, die Definition beschreibt die Worte und deren Bedeutung. Aber ist es nicht so, dass wegen der "relativ automatischen" Frage eben durchaus eher das Gegenteil vermittelt werden soll so nach Art der "rhetorischen Frage" die Antwort impliziert ohne sie zu geben?

Comment: @Uwe nein, sehe ich nicht so. Sie läßt eben nur so viel Spielraum zu, dass der Empfänger das unterstellen *kann* - er kann's aber auch lassen. Das Zulassen dieses Spielraums kann Absicht sein oder nicht.

Comment: @tofro: Deine Antwort und deine Kommentare widersprechen sich. Wenn ich sage: "ich gebe mich geschlagen"; Woher soll dann folgende Frage (relativ automatisch) kommen: "Warum sollte er so tun, als ob er geschlagen wäre, wenn er es (*nicht?*) wirklich ist." Ich bin mir unsicher ob nicht in deiner antwort ein "nicht" fehlt, sonst ergibt die Frage an sich nicht viel Sinn.

Comment: @jarnbjo Ich sehe keinen Widerspruch (cui bono): Warum sollte man jemandem böse Absicht unterstellen, der sich als etwas (geschlagen) darstellt, was gar nicht in seinem Sinne ist? Das dürfte wohl selbstverständlich sein.

Comment: Ich werf jetzt einfach mal als Beispiel die Ilias ein, wo sich die Griechen "geschlagen" gaben und das mit dem Präsent eines Holzpferdes äußerlich  darstellten. Im Allgemeinen finde ich aber, dass "sich geschlagen geben" kein gutes Beispiel ist, da der Ausdruck schon viel zu idiomatisiert ist (als Synonym von "aufgeben", egal ob man dazu noch äußerliche Zeichen macht oder nicht).

Comment: @Annatar Das kommt vor - Alles Lug und Betrug. Darum habe ich im Kommentar oben extra den Wolf gewählt. Dem kann man die böse Absicht wohl kaum unterstellen. Das ändert aber nichts daran, dass "sich xxx geben" weder automatisch Betrug noch Ehrlichkeit unterstellt. Es läßt Spielraum für Zweifel, ja. Und das Erwecken von Zweifel *kann* Absicht sein oder nicht. Aber es heißt **nicht** automatisch "der tut nur so".

Comment: @jarnbo Vielleicht kannst du jetzt verstehen, warum da kein "nicht " steht.

Comment: Die Antwort hört sich für mich schlüssig an. Der "Raum für Zweifel" ist vermutlich der Grund warum ich öfters mal das Gefühl habe, dass der Schreiber das Gegenteil meint obwohl es von der Wortwahl her wohl doch nicht so geschrieben steht.

Answer (score 0):

Gute Frage.
Ich habe jetzt keine Quelle, aber ich denke, es kommt von "sich für etwas ausgeben". Damit wäre ich Deiner Meinung, dass der Schreiber der Schlagzeile eine Lüge/ ein Schauspiel unterstellt.

Answer (score 0):

Wenn Sie "sich unschuldig geben" benutzen, müssen Sie wissen, dass der Handelnde nicht unschuldig war: "Vor Gericht gab er sich unschuldig, kam damit jedoch nicht durch." Wenn Sie neutral berichten möchten, könnten Sie schreiben: "Vor Gericht erklärt er sich unschuldig.", "Vor Gericht beteuert er seine Unschuld.", "Vor Gericht weist er jede Schuld von sich." - "Sich als (etwas) (aus-)geben" kennzeichnet klar eine Verstellung oder einen Betrug. Im Theater heißt es auch: "Die Schauspielerin XY gab die Rolle der Esmelda."

Comment: Das ist wieder so eine Verwendung wo ich den starken Eindruck habe, dass das Gegenteil behauptet werden soll. Mir geht es übrigens nicht darum selbst etwas zu schreiben aber ich bin in letzter Zeit in der Presse bei Fällen in denen noch nichts bekannt war von den Journalisten diese Redewendung genutzt wurde. Es hört sich für mich sehr reißerisch und (ab)wertend an für eine Berichterstattung die neutral sein will.